# Spring JPA Repository n+1 problems, EBEAN alternative

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ebean

I'm in the process of writing a Java based server for an existing MySQL database. I can change the structure of the database, yet any change also means digging through a quite old CakePHP project and I'd like to leave that one untouched as much as possible.

I have not very much experience with database access in Java, so when I started looking for a good framework, I ended up with Spring Data Repositories (mostly because I already had Spring Boot Actuator for REST services) and because rolling Hibernate or other JPA implementations manually seemed tedious and complex.

The problem now is, that my queries are not very fast. An example is querying my ~200 users, and loading up their association (user.groups, user.groups.rights, user.groups.rights.permissions, user.rights, user.rights.permissions, users.nfc_keys). I need all this data because one of the clients connected to the Java Server needs this information to login users, even in case the main server goes down and also to speedup login (in other words, it caches the information).

The problem is, the query takes a whopping 8 seconds to perform! I'm aware of the problems, the n+1 problem to be specific. Because all my Collections are lazy loaded, hibernate queries the groups, groups.rights,.... individually for each user. For example my group field looks like this:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_group_memberships",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
)
private List<Group> groups;
```

I tried changing FetchType to EAGER, the only thing this does is, fetch all the groups eagerly with the query, but not with an SQL-join, but again by doing n-queries.

I had a look at [this blog post](http://www.kumaranuj.com/2013/07/jpa-2-fetch-joins-and-whether-we-should.html) and implemented a query in the UserRepository loading the information using a LEFT JOIN FETCH, the needed to change from Lists to Sets, get annoyed about null pointer problems due to my hashCode/equals implementation and again lazy loading / set proxies, to find out that the query time was reduced to about 2 seconds, which is not bad, but still very slow compared to what CakePHP takes to do the same query.

My question now is mostly: Are there straightforward solutions to solve those kind of problems using Spring Data Repositories or am I better of switching to a different framework (which would be possible still in this early project phase)? I specifically looked at Ebeans used in the Play framework, and they seem to have a really nice API and also allow defining fetch paths (which should solve the n+1 problem much nicer), however I also read about the project being poorly maintained. What are your opinions?

Comment: You need to enable query logging, and study the query plans created by MySql.  If the query is not using indexes that you expect (you see table-scans, etc.) you may have to add indexes or craft the query by hand.

Answer (score 2):

Note that I am biased as I am the main maintainer of Ebean ORM.

One of the main reasons Ebean exists is because it is my opinion that JPQL is poorly designed to optimize ORM queries/object graph construction. Specifically the lack of support for '**partial objects**' and '**fetch paths**'. To some extent JPA fetch groups attempt to solve these issues but yes you noted that both of these issues are dealt with directly by Ebeans query language. JPA fetch groups fall short IMO (mixed object graph construction from DB, L2, and L3 for example).

Note that I purposely kept Ebean low profile during a busy period in life (kids etc). Ebean ORM has a sponsor and if you look at the project releases you will see it is in good health.

Ebean ORM is actually coming up to 10 years old so it is not exactly a new or young project.

Just recently **ElasticSearch integration** has been released with the ability to build object graphs (or paths of the object graph) from ElasticSearch. This can add provide read scalability without loading the database.

Additionally, you may know that Ebean can profile the application and automatically tune ORM queries (check the video on that if you have not).

Hopefully, that helps.
Cheers, Rob.

**Update:** 
Adding some links to refer to for people interested in the details (and avoiding N + 1, optimizing ORM queries etc):

- **N + 1** https://ebean.io/docs/query/background/nplus1
- **Partial objects** https://ebean.io/docs/query/background/partialobjects
- **Automatic query tuning** https://ebean.io/docs/query/background/autotune
- **ElasticSearch** https://ebean.io/docs/features/elasticsearch/

Answer (score 0):

Query speed related to many thing :

> 1.Driver - 2.Database - 3.Connection pooling config

As my experience for JPA :

> try to open session in View layer and and try to use HikariCP will
>   speedup connection speed

Comment: We'll for my test I did kind of a microbenchmark. JUnit test running only this query, can those kind of problems really be solved by using a different connection pool??

Comment: some connection pooling using blocks ,using diffirent concept ,that help connection never be tired .Also you now Java using for enterprice,it need more byte code than php also session will keep im memory ,php storing session in each req resp in disk ,help php to less memory usage ,As an alternative if you are familiar with sql ,use jdbctemplate using less memory and more speed